# Displaying pictures/photographs in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, jquery, image

I want a really nice way to load in pictures onto a webpage, like a portfolio of my work (let's say it's pottery that I sell on the web) - various fade effects and the like - what can you recommend?  Is there something in JQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most popular are probably:

- [lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox/)
- [lightbox2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)
- [thickbox jquery plugin](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of jQuery plugins that will do this for you.  One that I like is the [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) plugin.  There is also [Cycle Lite](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite/) if you don't need as many effects.  For more you can search the [jQuery plugin database](http://plugins.jquery.com/) for slideshow or carousel -- and perhaps other keywords.

Answer (score 1):

I really love [fancy](http://fancy.klade.lv/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the LightBox on my website and have not found anything easier to work with.  Best of all it is free.  Here is an example of the implementation on my website.

[Italy Pictures](http://www.rsolberg.com/Album.aspx?id=4)

You can download the Lightbox code [here](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/#download)...

Answer (score 0):

[Lightbox 2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) may be worth a look. Nice way of loading images from thumbnail links. Very simple to implement too.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what has already been mentioned, I have used slideshowpro and really like it. A very inexpensive download (like $20 or something like that), its free to try, and widely used. It is a flash plugin however, so you need to be OK with that (you don't need to know flash to use it)

Its use xml files to define the gallery/pictures and has a lot of easily configurable options. Also has an add-in for Picasa that will automatically generate the XML for you from a list of files.

http://slideshowpro.net/